# During Shivah must the mourner always sit on a low stool?

Tags: mourning-aveilus

During the Shivah period, does one have to sit on a low stool all of the time or only when visitors are present?

Answer (score 4):

The Maharshal writes that the mourner must sit on the low stool when visitors are present, however [the Taz](https://www.sefaria.org/Turei_Zahav_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.387.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) (and the [Shach](https://www.sefaria.org/Siftei_Kohen_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.387.1.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) seems to concur) understands this to mean that the mourner doesn't have to sit at all when visitors are not present - he can stand up and walk around. Whenever the mourner *does* sit, it must be on a low stool, regardless of the presence or absence of visitors.